# UITableViewCell subclass gets build error on all super methods

Tags: objective-c, ios

In Xcode 4, I create a subclass of UITableViewCell through the "New File..." menu. I checked the "targeted for iPad" and "With XIB for user interface" boxes. Then I immediately start getting build errors to this effect:

**Automatic Reference Counting Issue -
Receiver type 'UITableViewCell' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'viewDidLoad'**

I get 4 of these errors, one for each super method called.

Again this is a clean file created from the template with no extra changes. I haven't had problems with building any other classes that implement functions like viewDidLoad, etc. just UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` is a subclass of `UIView`, not `UIViewController`. The `viewDidLoad:` method is defined in `UIViewController`.

You might want to move your code into the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method instead.

Comment: Ah! so when I selected viewcontroller subclass and and told it tableviewcell, Xcode assumed that I wasn't stupid and threw that code in anyway. Big mistake.